# Prove that $\int_{1}^{a} \frac 1t dt + \int_{1}^{b} \frac 1t dt = \int_{1}^{ab} \frac 1t dt$

Tags: calculus, integration

Prove that
$$\int_{1}^{a} \frac 1t dt + \int_{1}^{b} \frac 1t dt = \int_{1}^{ab} \frac 1t dt$$

Useful facts:  $\int_{1}^{a}  \frac 1t dt$ can be written as $\int_{b}^{ab} \frac 1t dt$


Every partition $P=${$t_0,...,t_n$} on $[1,a]$ gives rise to a partition $P'=${$bt_0,...,bt_n$} on $[b,ab]$, and conversely.

I have to do the question without actually integrating it, since the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus was not proven yet.

Comment: Integral of 1/t is log...

Comment: You can just integrate it.

Comment: Your answerers are assuming that this question comes after you have learned the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, but the $P=$ part of the question indicates you need to compute the integral from scratch using Riemann Sums.  Can you clarify?

Comment: I think I have to use the fact that $$U(f,P)-L(f,P) < \epsilon$$

Comment: Ah, Spivak, my old friend.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang I haven't proven the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus yet, so I can only use partitions.

Comment: @Senya Then prove the fundamental theorem of calculus in your homework and use our solutions. Can it get any simpler than that?

Comment: @Shahar The instructor is fussy about that sort of thing. He wants what he wants, and currently he wants us to use it without the Fundamental Theorem of calculus.

Comment: @Senya the point of a course like this is to construct calculus from the basic ideas, so you need to work with only what is agreed upon.  This is how higher math is done. It can really be an eye-opening experience; I hope you enjoy it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the partitions $P$ and $P'$ be as given.

Notice that

$$ \frac{1}{b} \cdot \text{inf}\{\frac{1}{t} : t_{i-1} \leq t \leq t_i \} = \text{inf}\{\frac{1}{t} : bt_{i-1} \leq x \leq bt_i \}$$

Now we can show equivalence between the two partitions in the following way :

Let the first inf above be $m_i$ and the second be $m'_i$, then we have

$$\begin{align*} L(f, P') &= \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n m'_i (bt_{i} - bt_{i -1}) \\
                          &= \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n bm'_i (t_{i} - t_{i -1}) \\
                          &= \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n m_i (t_{i} - t_{i -1}) \\
                          &= L(f, P) \end{align*} $$

Since these lower step functions are the same, we can conclude that

$$ \text{sup}\{L(f, P)\} = \text{sup}\{L(f, P')\}$$

and thus that
$$\int_{1}^{a} \frac{1}{t} dt = \int_{a}^{ab} \frac{1}{t} dt $$

Now we need only plug this in to

$$\int_{1}^{a} \frac{1}{t} dt + \int_{1}^{b} \frac{1}{t} dt = \int_{1}^{ab} \frac{1}{t} $$

and remember that

$$\int_{a}^{b} f + \int_{b}^{c} f = \int_{a}^{c} f $$

to complete the proof.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your beautiful answer but I wanted to know in the initial step how you can justify the $\frac 1b$ in the third line. I understand what it is intuitively, but does it have to be formally presented or is it just trivial/obvious?

Comment: @Senya I had a longer explanation typed up, but the formatting was off. In any case, I think you should be fine taking it as obvious. Perhaps note that the smallest value on an interval in the new partition corresponds the the smallest value on the same $i^{th}$ interval of the old partition, simply multiplied by b.

Comment: Thank you ever so much for your help! Also, could a similar proof be used for something similar, such as $\int_a^b f(x) dx = \int_{a+c}^{b+c} f(x-c) dx?$

Comment: @Senya The idea is very similar, yes. You must notice the link between the partitions for the first integral and those of the second. But yes, very similar ideas.

Comment: Sorry if I'm asking too much but, what is the link between them?

Comment: If P is a partition {t_0, t_1, ... t_n} of [a, b] and g(x) = f(x-c) then inf{f(x) : t_{i-1} <= x <= t_{i}} = inf{g(x) : t_{i-1} + c <= x <= t_{i} + c}

Answer (score 4):

Since $\int_1^a \frac{1}{t}\, dt = \int_b^{ab} \frac{1}{u}\, du$ (using the $u$-sub $u = tb$), we have $$\int_1^a \frac{1}{t}\, dt + \int_1^b \frac{dt}{t} = \int_b^{ab} \frac{1}{u}\, du + \int_1^b \frac{1}{t}\, dt = \int_1^b \frac{1}{t}\, dt + \int_b^{ab} \frac{1}{t}\, dt = \int_1^{ab} \frac{1}{t}\, dt.$$

Comment: Sorry, but what is the u-sub?

Comment: I mean $u$-substitution.

Comment: Ordinarily this would work, but not in the context of this problem which requires a proof from partitions.

Answer (score 1):

Simply, use the change change of variable $u = b\cdot t$ in the first integral, or $u = a \cdot t$ in the second integral, then use Chasles's relation.

Answer (score 1):

Abuse your `useful fact`:

$$\int_{1}^{a} \frac 1t dt + \int_{1}^{b} \frac 1t dt=\int_b^{ab}\frac1t dt+ \int_{1}^{b} \frac 1t dt =-\int_{ab}^{b}\frac1t dt- \int_{b}^{1} \frac 1t dt = -\left(\underbrace{\int_{ab}^{b}\frac1t dt+ \int_{b}^{1} \frac 1t dt}_{\int_{ab}^1\frac1{t}dt}\right)=\;\therefore \int_1^{ab}\frac1{t}dt$$

Other useful facts used:

$$\int_a^bf(t)dt=-\int_b^af(t)dt$$

$$\int_a^bf(t)dt+\int_b^cf(t)dt=\int_a^cf(t)dt$$

Answer (score 1):

Following the hint, you want to show that
\begin{align}
U(f,P) &= U(f,P') \\  L(f,P) &= L(f,P')
\end{align}
Therefore
$$
\int_1^a \frac{1}{t}\,dt = \int_b^{ab} \frac{1}{t}\,dt
$$

Comment: Wait, how is the last part implemented? The fact that $\int_{1}^{a} \frac 1t dt = \int_b^{ab} \frac 1t dt$

Comment: The left hand side is the greatest lower bound of $U(f,P)$, and the right hand side is the greatest lower bound of $U(f,P')$. Does that help?

Comment: Oh, okay. I think I understand. Thank you for the clarification.